# jenkins - error while deploying tomcat war - curl: (56) Recv failure

Tags: ubuntu, curl, jenkins, ubuntu-12.04

I setup jenkins on one ec2 machine & deploying war file on second ec2 machine. from jenkins when I am sending following command.

```
http://username:password@ec-machine-address:8080/manager/text/undeploy?path=/
```

jenkins running in infinite loop. When I try same command on terminal I receive following error.

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

It was working fine some time back & I deployed war  6-7 times. But suddenly I am receiving this error. I dont think, I change in jenkins setup. So maybe this is something to do with server blocking request from jenkins ec2. Not sure though whats problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its nothing to do with ubuntu, its firewall. Disabling firewall did the trick.